# How do I recognize key on numpad is being clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I use `bind()` to set actions for keys, but when I want to add action to number keys on Numpad it doesn't work. How should the code look if I want it to work?

Comment: [Tk/tcl man pages](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/bind.htm) may have the info you need?

Comment: Related: https://gist.github.com/irmen/2c9d6bb0afb16b464805410c108a2885

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on the state of the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> key.

To identify which key has been pressed, the tkinter `event` object has three attributes: `char`, `keysym` and `keycode`.

Focussing on the keypad numbers, with <kbd>NumLock</kbd> ON these are (0-9):

```
char    keysym      keycode
'0'     '0'         96
'1'     '1'         97
'2'     '2'         98
'3'     '3'         99
'4'     '4'         100
'5'     '5'         101
'6'     '6'         102
'7'     '7'         103
'8'     '8'         104
'9'     '9'         105
```

With <kbd>NumLock</kbd> OFF these are (0-9):

```
char    keysym      keycode
''      'Insert'    45
''      'End'       35
''      'Down'      40
''      'Next'      34
''      'Left'      37
''      'Clear'     12
''      'Right'     39
''      'Home'      36
''      'Up'        38
''      'Prior'     33
```

Now, for the numbers (so <kbd>NumLock</kbd> ON), the `char` and `keysym` are the same, but `keycode` is different for the numpad numbers and the normal row above the letters. For example, the <kbd>2</kbd> in the number row has `keycode` `50`, while the <kbd>2</kbd> in the numpad has `keycode` `98`.

However, with <kbd>NumLock</kbd> OFF, the keys are indistinguishable from the other keys with the same meaning. For example, both the normal <kbd>End</kbd> and the one under the <kbd>1</kbd> in the keypad have `keycode` `35`.

So to check for the <kbd>1</kbd> key on the numpad regardless of the state of <kbd>NumLock</kbd>, you need to check for the `keycode` being either `97` or `35`. However, this does mean that pressing the regular <kbd>End</kbd> key will have the same effect and I don't know of any way to stop this.

---

I used the following code to check all values posted above:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def key(event):
    print(repr(event.char), repr(event.keysym), repr(event.keycode))

root.bind("<Key>", key)
root.mainloop()
```