# How to bind keys-numbers on numpad?

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

How to bind number keys (numpad) for calculator ?
for example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
bu1=ttk.Button(root, text="Button 1")
bu1.bind('??', lambda: BuClick(1))
bu1.pack()
def BuClick(n):
    print(n)
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks..

Comment: Are you aware that the button widget has a `command` option?

Comment: Yes, I mean for example when I press number 1 on keyboard so it will perform the task..

Comment: Ok I was no sure from the question. You should check the documentation about event binding in tkinter (for instance [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html)).

Comment: Buttons don't usually have keyboard focus so you should do the binding on `root` rather than on `bu1`.

Comment: Thanks @j_4321, thats right !

Comment: Keep in mind that dealing with the numpad can be difficult because the events are different when NumLock is on or off. For example, it's impossible to distinguish between pressing the "1" button on the numpad with NumLock off and pressing the regular "End" button, also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52202252/3714930).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code to bind all your number keys at once:

```
import tkinter as tk

def my_handler(e):
    print(e.char)

master = tk.Tk()
for i in range(10):
    master.bind(str(i), my_handler)
master.mainloop()
```