# Bind key to just the numpad 1

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple code the creates 2 circles and keys that change the filling colors and changes texts upside them. I binded the keys to 7 and 1 on my keyboard but I just want it to work on Numpad and not the other 7 and 1.

```
window.bind("7", onKeyPressRec)
window.bind("1", onKeyPressSave)
```

I have tried "num7", "numpad7" etc. but they didnt work hope someone can help me thanks in advance!

Comment: [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198795/how-do-i-recognize-key-on-numpad-is-being-clicked)

Answer (score 1):

[This Tk manual page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.html) has keypad keys prefixed with KP_, so KP_1 and KP_7 should work.

Comment: Well I have also tried this and it didn't work window.bind("KP_7", onKeyPressRec)

Comment: It looks like you need to surround the key name with `<>` from the [tkinter man page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events) so does `window.bind("<KP_7>", onKeyPressRec)` work?